# Is "null this" an acceptable use of extension methods?

Tags: c#, .net, null, extension-methods, guid

So, I really enjoy using extension methods.. maybe a bit too much. So, I'm going to ask about my latest enjoyment to ensure that I'm not going too far.

Scenario is that we have a `Guid?` variable that gets passed in. If the variable is null or `Guid.Empty`, then we want to use a different Guid. So, I wrote an extension method to make it read like English:

```
    internal static Guid OrIfEmpty(this Guid? guid, Guid other)
    {
        if (!guid.HasValue || guid.Value == Guid.Empty)
        {
            return other;
        }
        return guid.Value;
    }
```

This automatically implies that a "null this" will not throw an exception. For instance, this will work:

```
((Guid?)null).OrIfEmpty(other);
```

This is not possible without using extension methods, and in my opinion can be quite misleading. However, it's just so concise and clean! So, what do you think? Is this an acceptable thing to do or could it be too confusing to other programmers?

Also, I'm sure there will be other scenarios where I do things like this and checking `this` for null, but this is the best example I have right now.

Note: I'm not really asking about this `Guid?` business in particular. I'm asking more about the overall pattern implemented (having an extension method where the `this` can be `null`)

Comment: `(Guid?)null`is not a null GUID, it's a valid instance of `Nullable<Guid>` that happens to contain a null value.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it doesn't check for `Guid.Empty` though

Comment: Does a null Guid implicitly convert to Guid.Empty when passed to a non nullable param? If so can you not just use the non-null guid and check if it's empty, and always be able to use the extension regardless of nullable-ness? Worth a check in VS...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, but this applies equally to actual reference types. I tested it to make sure. You can have an extension on `object` and do `((object)null).MyExtension()` and it won't throw an exception

Comment: And note his text: [make it read like English]. I don't see why not implementing it as an extension considering that argument

Comment: @AustinSalonen it is! Heh, question is about the pattern then. I didn't realize that existed!... Well, wait. That doesn't handle Guid.Empty :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is not possible without using extension methods

Sure it is, just make is a regular static method call (which is all extension methods are):

> in my opinion can be quite misleading

I agree, since it *looks like* you're calling an instance method on a `null` instance.  It could be worse:

```
string s = null;
string n = s.OrIfEmpty("empty");
```

At first glance this looks like an obvious `NullReferenceException` waiting to happen, but it compiles and works as designed.

Since your question is really just soliciting opinions, there's not one right answer, but I certainly would be cautious and document the extension method to indicate that the `this` parameter could be `null`. Or (as @quezalcoatl implies) rename it to be more explicit that it supports `null` values:

```
internal static Guid OrIfNullOrEmpty(this Guid? guid, Guid other)
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhitespace` ? :) it's all about proper naming!

Comment: It is relevant to note that this is done fairly commonly, it's not like there's a stigma that you should never use `null` for the first argument of an extension method.  The key point here though is realizing that an extension method is just another static method, not an instance method.

Comment: @Servy - good point.  My only concern was the OP's example that at first glance looks to be calling an instance method on a null variable.  Since my natural gravity is to avoid `NullReferenceException`s, it just _looks_ odd to me.

Comment: @DStanley I intentionally avoided stating whether it was good or bad, I was merely saying a lot of people do do it (including myself, because I consider it a useful technique).  Whether or not it *should* be done is really a very subjective question.

Comment: @Servy: It's too bad there's no syntactical distinction between doing something to a reference value, versus doing something to the object referenced thereby (as existed to some extent in C with `.` versus `->`).  Even if it would seem odd that an extension method `someString.IsNullOrEmpty()` wouldn't fail if `someString` is null, notating it as `String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString)` is decidedly un-oop-ish.  If it could have been notated as `String..IsNullOrEmpty`, that could have scored the best of both worlds.

Comment: @supercat You're right, it is un-OOP-ish.  C# has made it quite clear that as a language conforming to the definition of OOP is not a goal.  Their goal is to provide a practical language most useful to LOB developers.  Extension methods help with that, partly because syntactically `somestring.IsNulLOrEmpty()` is easier to write in VS than the non-extension version, and once you're used to it it reads better (in my opinion).  This is a useful language feature *despite* the fact that it violated OOP concepts.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry I muddled my meaning.  I think `someString.IsNullOrEmpty()` is the better notation, and `String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString)` is hideosly-un-oopish.  The former would be even better if there were a syntax for members that would indicate that they operate on the value of a reference rather than upon the object to which the reference points, and if it could be part of the class to which it applies [class `Foo` shouldn't be able to declare extension members for other classes, but should be able to declare them for itself].

Answer (score 3):

I personally I think there will be much more developers that understand better and faster (so in the end means the code is cleaner):

```
if (!guid.HasValue || guid.Value == Guid.Empty)
{
    return other;
}
```

Rather than:

```
((Guid?)null).OrIfEmpty(other);
```

So it depends if you're coding for yourself or what you write could be supported by others. Personally I don't think the value added is worth the "weirdness" :)

Comment: ((Guid?)null).OrIfEmpty(other) is just what he used as an examle to proof it works...

Comment: I generally agree with not introducing new extensionmethods all the time. The problem with the first one is that it's a statement, not an expression. So in some places, such as LINQ it's a bit annoying.

Comment: It was that way at first, but this check has to be done like 20 times(code duplication is evil and horrible). It could be a plain helper method though rather than an extension like `OrIfEmpty(guid, other);`

Comment: @Iboshuizen: I know but the effect will be the same if you're calling the method over a null object ...

Comment: @Earlz: what about using a simple static helper without using the extension? That way passing a null argument wouldn't be as weird as with the extension syntax ... what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

In general, an extension method should check for null values. After all, an extension method is nothing more than a static method with some syntactic sugar added so that the compiler can treat it like an instance method.

For example, if you have this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Frob<TSource>(this TSource source)
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

You can then call it two different ways:

```
var foo = new List<int>();
var bar = foo.Frob();  // called like an instance method
var barby = MyExtensions.Frob(foo); // called like a static method
```

Whereas with a normal instance method you can assume that `this` is not null, you can't make that assumption with an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problem with that. Just recall the

`string.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhitespace`

that comes from stdlib.

In general, it depends on **what** will you do on that null case. If you use the function in a normal way, and if the function behaves normally with that special case - all's ok. But if your function gets into debug mode and starts reconfiguring the system, well, you've crossed the Principle-of-Least-Astonishment and that is *not good*

-- note: as @JeppeStigNielsen accurately pointed out, the INOEOW is **not** an extension method in the current version of .Net. I am sure that I had it a few times as extension method, but most probably it was on some CTP version or maybe it was custom addon for old versions of .Net where it didn't exist at all. Sorry for the confusion! Nevertheless, "it's all about proper naming" stil holds! :)

Comment: In general, I agree, though I'd probably implement it as a hybrid of this approach and the one he outlined: implement `IsNullOrEmpty` that returns a boolean indicating whether it does not have a value or is equal to Guid.Empty (he already has that code) and then the consumer can decide how to deal with that.

Comment: So, something like `myGuid.IsNullOrEmpty() ? other : myGuid.Value`.

Comment: Yeah, I'd do it exactly in that way, because it is succint and other code-readers would instantly know everything.

Comment: The authors of the framework didn't choose to make `IsNullOrEmptyOrWhitespace` an extension method, so it's not similar. Regarding your comment: One can say `myGuid ?? other` directly in C#, but it only checks for `null`, not for `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

Comment: yes, indeed. this is exactly why I deleted the comment about coalesce. As I wrote the comment it occurred to me that the 'coalesce' already exists :)

Comment: Hm. Now you surprised me! It really is not extension method! Very strange, I was absolutely  sure it is extension, though I always deliberately have written it in full form. I remember it very well from some earlier .Net versions that it **was** an extension at some point of time.. Maybe I had some some CTP and maybe it was later reintroduced to the framework.. Sorry for the confusion :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is OK. Note that the example with `Nullable<Guid>` is not *that* bad, since so-called `null` of type `Nullable<Guid>` is a real and existing value of `Nullable<Guid>`, not "nothing".

That's why you can also use instance methods on this kind of "null", as in

```
Guid? g = null;
g.GetValueOrDefault();  // OK; real instance method
```

Using this with a reference type is even more "strange":

```
internal static string OrIfEmpty(this string str, string other)
{
  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? other : str;
}
```

Because then you can call it on a "real" null:

```
string s = null;
s.OrIfEmpty("unspecified");  // OK; s is a true null reference
```

Comment: It's actually not that uncommon to have methods like this on reference types that *really* have a null value.