# In C#, what is the cleanest way to do an Any() that includes the null case?

Tags: c#, linq

i have the following code in C#:

```
 if (this.Trucks.Any() || this.Cars.Any())
 {
      return true;
 }
 return false;
```

but i just realized that sometimes one or either of these arrays is null so in my case i wan null to just return false (instead of throwing exception).

I could add upfront null checks like this:

```
 if ((this.Trucks != null && this.Trucks.Any()) || 
    (this.Cars != null && this.Cars.Any()))
 {
    return true;
 }
  return false;
 }
```

but wanted to see if there was a cleaner way

Comment: Make an extension method that returns false if the item is empty  or null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565881/is-null-this-an-acceptable-use-of-extension-methods

Comment: Have you thought about catching the exception thrown?

Comment: [**!!!!Collections Should Never Be Null!!!!**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1970001/643085). I can't stress this enough. Set `this.Trucks` and `this.Cars = new List<Whatever>()` in the constructor or something.

Comment: Migrate from C# to F#

Comment: And please just return the result of the boolean expression instead of true/false.

Comment: I usually use coalesce operator `(this.Trucks ?? new Truck[0]).Any()` or an extension method containing it (see `EmptyIfNull` answer)

Comment: @HighCore: that's definitely true. But sometimes you are forced to use old or bad written API that you can't change and that work with nulls :(

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815641/elegant-way-to-avoid-nullreferenceexception-in-c-sharp

Comment: Extension methods should look and behave like instance methods because a compatible instance method might be added in the future. So, any extension method receiving a null reference should throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your own implementation:

```
public static Class StaticHelpers
{
    public static bool AnyEx<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        if (enumerable == null) return false;

        return enumerable.Any();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (this.Trucks.AnyEx() || this.Cars.AnyEx())
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: @AK_ You can make the argument that having `null` collections is a bad idea (and there have been some good comments on the matter), but don't call it an error. I'd argue that it's not. If you can't assume that collections are `null`, this is one way to solve that problem.

Comment: I'm not saying its an error, I'm saying you have taken something bad, and made it worse.

Comment: Extension methods should look and behave like instance methods because a compatible instance method might be added in the future. So, any extension method receiving a null reference should throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado counter-point: `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. In general, I agree though.

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. and `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` are not extension methods and are the right way to do it in this case also.

Answer (score 4):

I would create an extension method if you want to trate a null sequence as an empty one:

```
public static class Seq
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        return seq ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}

return this.Trucks.EmptyIfNull().Any() || this.Cars.EmptyIfNull().Any()
```

If you don't like having an extension method handling null values you could remove the `this` modifier and use

```
return Seq.EmptyIfNull(this.Trucks).Any() || Seq.EmptyIfNull(this.Cars).Any()
```

Comment: The concept of a `null IEnumerable` is somewhat troubling and as you can see, difficult to deal with. I always try to return `Enumerable.Empty<T>` instead of `null` when possible and this is a clean way of forcing that. This little extension method should be part of every developer's bag of tricks.

Comment: Extension methods should look and behave like instance methods because a compatible instance method might be added in the future. So, any extension method receiving a null reference should throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado - You couldn't add a compatible instance method in future - the entire point is to handle null so throwing an NRE defeats the point.

Comment: @AK_, I don't understand your comment. You can't call a method on an null instance and you should be able to in an extension method.

Comment: @Lee, I can't add instance methods to `IEnumerable<T>`, but Microsoft can. We are assuming `Trucks` is an `IEnumerable<T>` but it could be a `IMyCollection<T>` which means I could add instance methods to it. If you follow that golden rule, you won't be bitten by this in the future.

Comment: @PauloMorgado - No-one can add an instance method which converts a null sequence to an empty one.

Comment: @Lee, who said someone could? I didn't!

Comment: @PauloMorgado - You just said "I can't add instance methods to `IEnumerable<T>`, but Microsoft can". Neither Microsoft nor anyone else could add anything to `IEnumerable<T>` to do what this extension method does. Your entire argument was that this method could cause problems since "a compatible instance method might be added in the future", however no such instance method could be added.

Comment: By compatible I meant "same name and same arguments". And, by the way, if you own the code you can add any instance method you want. It's the user of the class that can't call instance methods on null instances. And the same should go for extension methods. Do you know any BCL extension method that allows to extend null instnaces?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Your first issue applies to any extension method and the spec defines what happens in that case. It seems your real objection is having an extension method which handles nulls, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: I don't have a personal issue with anything. I'm just pointing out that the intention behind the design of extension methods was for them to be used and behave as instance methods. That makes your `Seq.EmtyIfNull<T>` method a wrong use of extension methods. Just make it a "normal" static method and use it like this: `Seq.EmptyIfNull(this.Trucks).Any()`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you to keep with non-null contracts (null object pattern) as much as possible. That mean you will initialize probably in constructor empty array ( `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` in case of `IEnumerable` - in case of array add `.ToArray()` ). The problem with null checking is that is usually spread and multiplied over code - complexity of code (and unit tests) unnecessarily grows. It is easier to forget check for null in `x` places than forgetting to initialize empty object in one place. You can also use [`Code contracts`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) library to check your "contracts" on runtime. In fact inventor of "`null`" call it's the billion dollar mistake: ["Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake"](http://qconlondon.com/london-2009/presentation/Null+References%3a+The+Billion+Dollar+Mistake)

Answer (score 1):

How about you just check them in the main `if` condition:

```
if ((this.Trucks != null && this.Trucks.Any()) || 
    (this.Cars != null && this.Cars.Any()))
{
  return true;
}
return false;
```

This can be rewritten as one long line:

```
return ((this.Trucks != null && this.Trucks.Any()) || 
        (this.Cars != null && this.Cars.Any()));
```

Comment: this is what i have above. .  i was just asking to see if there was something cleaner . . looks like extention method is probably the way to go

Comment: Extension methods are a trade-off. More concise, "cleaner" code up front, but hides more of the logic of what you are doing.

Comment: I agree. I think this is the "cleanest" way to do it, apart from simply guaranteeing the collections are never null in the first place (eg `readonly` lists initialized in ctor).